# Why isn't this statement logging even though the UI changes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following React component:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  console.log("Hello, World!");

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
    console.log("handleClick");
  };
 
  return (
    <main>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        a button
      </button>
      <div>
        {isClicked && <p>cool, clicked</p>}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
```

Pretty simple. When I run `npm run dev`, I see the following logs:

```
 ✓ Ready in 1252ms
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 905ms (465 modules)
Hello, World!
```

Makes sense that `Hello, World!` is printed on render. In terms of UI, I see:

[image]

When I click the button in the UI, I see:

[image]

Great! That means that `isClicked` got set to true. In other words, `handleClick` executed.

However, I don't see `handleClick` logged to console (nothing new has appeared below `Hello World`)

Why is that? I would have expected it to appear.

Comment: Is this a server-rendered application? If so, your first log statement is executed on the server, whereas the interactivity (e.g. button presses) happen on the client. Have you checked the browser console in dev tools?

Comment: Oh! No I haven't. Lemme try that ...

Answer (score 0):

h/t @argbo - the client logs are visible in the browser console in dev tools